# How to use NTML Authentication in Angular 4 - Django REST project

Tags: django, angular, django-rest-framework, windows-authentication

In our project the frontend UI is being developed in Angular 4 which is ultimately communicating (calling REST APIs) with the backend Django REST Framework. Both are running in Linux Server.

For authentication purpose we have to use the window NTML authentication system.
We have to access the Active Directory to get access to the usernames and passwords for the users.

For the first time users have to login using their own username & password, but after that from next logins (homepage URL hit from browser) the application will not prompt for the login credentials (login page will not appear) like other company web-apps that are running in system.

It will be helpful if anyone can provide the steps to be perform to implement this type of authentication system.

- Setup required at Django REST Framework, i.e. our backend
- Setup required at Angular 4, i.e. our frontend.
- Setup required at system level (OS level).

Thanks in advance.